# Display material preview in custom panel

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I have created the material preview box in the custom panel by using the following code for the active material

`layout.template_preview(bpy.context.object.active_material)`

And the preview box was added, but now when I update the material using the custom panel, the preview does not update. Can Anyone help me!

Comment: IIRC it's tied in with the context.material of the material tab of the PROPERTIES panel & is more hassle than it's worth to get working otherwise.  You may find the following links useful. http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?261311-Does-anyone-know-how-to-display-the-BI-material-preview&p=2169931&viewfull=1#post2169931 and   http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?331963-moving-panels-possible-or-imposible